# Timestamp of restart of spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a microservice based on spring boot. I have a spring cloud configserver as well in-place. So depending upon the changes in the configserver microservice restart automatically. 
So now i need to grab the timestamp when the application got restarted. 
Is it possible to do so in the same microservice?

Comment: Offtopic-hint: There are mechanics where your application doesn't need to restart while reloading/updating some configs/properties. You can do that on the fly and avoid a downtime/restart time.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to spring events such as the ContextStartedEvent. There's a tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-events) that lays it out:

```
@EventListener
public void handleContextStartedEvent(ContextStartedEvent ctxStartEvt) {
    System.out.println("Context Start Event received.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, possible by adding the actuator and enabling the startup endpoint.

step1: Add the below dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

step2: Add the below property into the application.properties files.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=startup
```

step3: Setup a little amount of buffer memory to store the startup info and it won't affect the performance at anywhere in your application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartupTrackingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(StartupTrackingApplication.class);
        app.setApplicationStartup(new BufferingApplicationStartup(2048));
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

step: Hit the below URL using CURL like below or a POST call from POSTMAN. Then you will be seeing all startup-related info like when the startup started and ended. e.t.c.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/startup' -X POST | jq
```

For more explanation, view [reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuator-startup)

In the response json, node *"timeline"."startTime"* is the exact **startup timestamp** when the applicant has started its startup job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need this info in the java application itself. I don't want to hit the actuator endpoint to grab this info. i need this in application itself.

Comment: by default, when an spring application is restarting you will see the startup logs right ? i mean your logs will automatically have the restart log and no need to do extra task

Comment: I need this info to feed it into redis so that i can access this in configserver. That's why i need this info inside my microservice.